# Create a dynamic type for row data in ag grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, typescript-generics, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to develop an independent component using ag-grid. I will pass the column definitions to this independent component from my application so I set it up as an input property with a type like this:

```
interface ColumnDef {
  field: string;
  headerName: string;
}

@Input() colDef: ColumnDef[];
```

Now as you can see I can pass any number of columns I want from my host(where i will use this common component) application with a different id and that is working fine.

Now the requirement is I want to define the type for row data for ag-grid inside the common component dynamically also.

Suppose i pass column defs as:

```
[{field: 'colA', headerName: 'Col A'},
{field: 'colB', headerName: 'Col B'}]
```

So when the component receive this column defs, it should create dynamically a row data type as

```
interface rowData {
 colA: string;
 colB: string;
}
```

Similarly if i pass column definitions as

```
[{field: 'colA', headerName: 'Col A'},
{field: 'colB', headerName: 'Col B'},
{field: 'colC', headerName: 'Col C'}]
```

the row data type should be crated as

```
interface rowData {
 colA: string;
 colB: string;
 colC: string;
}
```

so that I can use this interface to type my row data.
Is there any way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given some array like this:

```
const colDef = [{field: 'colA', headerName: 'Col A'},
{field: 'colB', headerName: 'Col B'},
{field: 'colC', headerName: 'Col C'}] as const;
```

we can have these types:

```
type FieldNames<T> = T extends ReadonlyArray<{ field: infer U }> ? U : never;

type Rows<T> = FieldNames<T> extends string ? Record<FieldNames<T>, string> : never;
```

so that both

- `FieldNames<typeof colDef>` is `'colA' | 'colB' | 'colC'`
- `Rows<typeof colDef>` is `{ colA: string; colB: string; colC: string }`.

However, with your current `ColumnDef` type, `typeof colDef` is `ColumnDef`, and so `FieldNames<typeof colDef>` will be `Record<string, string>`, which is not particularly helpful. To fix this, we will need to add a type parameter to the component class like so:

```
class CustomGridComponent<T extends ColumnDef> implements OnInit /* or what have you */ { 
    @Input() colDef: ReadonlyArray<T> = [] as const;
    ... 
}
```

(by the way, using `ReadonlyArray` lets you get the types of your column definitions 'for free' by adding `as const` after the end of your array. If you are fine with manually defining some `interface ABCColDef { field: 'colA' | 'colB' | 'colC'; ... }` then `ReadonlyArray` is not necessary.)